# WCF service over HTTPS with custom UserNamePasswordValidator - how to handle blank username AND password

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, https

I have a WCFservice that is a HTTPS REST API which exposes a few `WebGet` methods. I am using transport level security over HTTPS. This is all working fine. I implemented a custom `UserNamePasswordValidator`, overriding the `Validate` method as per MSDN documentation.

```
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        WebFaultException rejectEx = new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        rejectEx.Data.Add("HttpStatusCode", rejectEx.StatusCode);

        if (null == userName || null == password)
            throw rejectEx;

        if (userName == "someusername" && password == "somepassword") return;

        throw rejectEx;            
    }
```

Accessing the service in a browser via HTTPS only (http is disabled), username and password are prompted for, leaving one out or entering one or both incorrectly results in the prompt coming back as I am throwing a 401.

The issue I have is that `Validate` is never called if both the username and password are left out when accessing the service. I need to be able to handle this and return an informative error, or even just a 401, to the browser/client.

Debugging shows that `Validate` is never fired when leaving out both the username and password. This means that in a browser you end up with a blank page and no errors.

How can I handle this situation and return a response to the client prompting for credentials again?

**Edit** to include config info:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RESTEndpointBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                                customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MyAPI.CustomAuthenticator, MyAPI"
                                />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="RESTEndpointBehaviour" name="MyAPI.RestService">
    <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpSSLBinding"
        contract="MyAPI.IRestService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://localhost:443" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>

<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpSSLBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: what does your service model section look like?

Comment: Are you referring to the `<service>` section of my `App.config`?

Comment: yes service section of it, but want to have a look at your bindings as well

Comment: edited to include config info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this puzzle by implementing a `serviceAuthorization` instead. As per the below blog article, with a few tweaks to match my application.

http://www.allenconway.net/2012/07/using-basic-authentication-in-rest.html

Comment: I'm coming at this from the opposite direction . I started with serviceAuthorization, but as far as I can see there is no way to return a 401 from there.